# How to set item in combobox in datagridview manually?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I want to set a value from the item collection of the combo box inside a datagridview without using a datasource.

```
    dtgLineMaster.Rows.Add()
   dtgLineMaster.Rows(rowcount).Cells(0).Value = reader3.GetString(2)
```

**It's showing a dialog error :** 
System.ArgumentExcpection: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.
To replace this default dialog please handle the DataError event.

Comment: Your list items and your reader3.GetString(2) probably don't match.  What drop down values do you have and what is the value of reader3.GetString(2) ?

Comment: If the item you are adding to the cells value is NOT already in the combo boxes items list… then you will get this `DataError.` As the error message suggest... I recommend wiring up the `DataGridView`’s `DataError` event to capture this error and it may reveal more info than you are currently getting. You do not say HOW are you setting the combo boxes initial items list?

Comment: Hi @LarsTech, Yes, the list item and the reader3.GetString() were not matching. The values had trailing whitespace in the database so it did'nt match. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create ***DataGridViewComboBoxColumn*** and bind into ***DataGridView***.

```
Dim dgvComboBox As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    dgvComboBox.HeaderText = "Select Data"
    dgvComboBox.Name = "dgvComboBox"
    dgvComboBox.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"})
    dtgLineMaster.Columns.Add(dgvComboBox)
```